# How to show mutliple cards with react flip card functionality?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I am trying to display multiple cards and based on clicks on each card the description card should flip. Currently when i click on "see more" in one card, all cards gets flipped. I want the flip change should be done based on click per card. Can you please help me accomplish this.

here is the code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-feynman-we6n9s?file=/src/App.js:141-155

Comment: both cards update the same state, `setFlip(!flip)`
you should have different state for each card

Comment: Thanks.. i tried to define the state and passed the id

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the state from a boolean, to an object, that map the card identifier to boolean

here is [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dubinsky-puyqvt?file=/src/App.js) how to achieve this (I used the `name` attribute as the key in the state object, but it can be achieved with other `id` attribute, or use the index)